# How can I read QRCodes in my UWP Windows 10 App

Tags: uwp, qr-code

I  have an application where I need to scan QRCodes. My application uses C#. .Net does not have option to parse QR codes. IS there a free option to parse QRCodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET does not classes to do this for your. The options above are good classes to include in your App. 
Another option is not to use a class but to use an API on the web like http://goqr.me/api/doc/read-qr-code/. You can sent the url of your image as a parameter and get the info back. This is useful in JavaScript based solution where you cannot use the .NET Classes.

Please remember to click “Mark as Answer” on the post that helps you, and to click “Unmark as Answer” if a marked post does not actually answer your question. Even if you are not the author of a thread you can always help others by voting as Helpful. This can be beneficial to other community members reading the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below options:

Barcode scanner sample on GitHub:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner

You can also use ZXing.Net - you can get it from NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [Zxing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) package. There are samples there you could have a look.

For example here, you can parse the QRCodes from a `WriteableBitma` like this:

```cs
private async void qrcode(WriteableBitmap bmp)
{
    IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
    // detect and decode the QRcode inside the writeablebitmap
    var result = reader.Decode(bmp);
    // do something with the result
    if (result != null)
    {
        //show QRCode's content
        txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
        txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;
    }
}
```